# Control DC motors in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, motordriver

I control two DC motors with BTS driver using raspberry.
In one file I have this:

```
def backwardFullSpeedBTS():
    rSpeed.ChangeDutyCycle(10)
    lSpeed.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

def forwardFullSpeedBTS():
    rSpeed.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    lSpeed.ChangeDutyCycle(10)

def stopBTSMotor():
    rSpeed.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    lSpeed.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

def start2ndMotor():
    rSpeed2.ChangeDutyCycle(80)
    lSpeed2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

def stop2ndMotor():
    rSpeed2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    lSpeed2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
```

In the next file I call the previous functions:

```
from MotorBTS import *

while GPIO.input(gpio_ButtonMStop) != 0:
"""Move arm outward until stop button pressed"""
   forwardFullSpeedBTS()
   pass
stopBTSMotor()  # stops Motor
    
cTime = float(time.time())
while checkDelay(cTime, 0.5):
   start2ndMotor()
   pass
stop2ndMotor()
```

Only it always calls me only the first engine and start2ndMotor never. The problem is that it only imports the first engine, but not the second. I tried splitting the engines into their own files, but it still didn't call the second engine.
Do you have any other way to call it or how to solve it?

Comment: What's are your error messages if there are some? May the 'ckeckDelay' responds with 'False'? You call the time.time() only once?!

Comment: There is no error message. The code continues on and "skips" this step. I then have time.time as follows
"def micros():
    return float(time.time())


def checkDelay(tstamp, dly):
    now = micros()
    diff = now - tstamp
    if (diff > dly):
        return False
    else:
        return True"

Comment: Which environment do you use? Maybe you do some debugging with, e.g. Visual Studio Code. And go step by step through the loop?!

Comment: What happens if you make the second param higher, e.g. 1.5 or 10?

Comment: I use PyCharm and then thony on raspberry. 

It has no effect. It just won't import.

Comment: What do you want to reach? The motor shall run for 0.5 seconds? The method itself works? I ask, since there is a different parameter inside?!